# Creating a macro variable have a list of dates in SAS

Tags: list, date, macros, sas

I am new to macro writing in SAS and being a proficient R user, I am having a difficult time understanding how to do things in SAS.
I am trying create a macro variable that contains the list of dates from a dataset.

My code is -

```
proc sql noprint;
select distinct sdate into : sdatem  separated by ' '
from work.date_list;
quit;

%put &sdatem;
```

But when I run this code, the code is executed without any errors but the %put statement in the log prints

```
 %put &sdatem;
```

and not the actual value. Any idea why this is happening? The dates are in yymmddn8. format.

The sample data I used is -

```
DATA compno_date_list; 
INPUT compno sdate; 
DATALINES; 
12490 20090120 
87432 20090120
24643 20090120
87432 20090119
12490 20090105
24643 20090105
;
proc print data=compno_date_list;
run;
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: If your code has run with errors recently it may have set the `OBS=` option to zero. Try running `OPTIONS OBS=MAX NOSYNTAXCHECK;` and then run the code again.

Comment: Tried this. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the line below the `%put` statement completely blank?

Comment: yes. You mean in the code or in the log? Both are blanks

Comment: What is returned in the log by the statement `%put foo &sdatem bar;`?

Comment: I get `%put foo &sdatem bar;` But also get a note saying `50             select distinct sdate into : sdatem  separated by  _
                                                                   49
NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.  Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended.
`

Comment: `%put` statements in the log should be followed by what they were asked to 'put'. If there's nothing in the log after the `%put` line, then consider restarting your SAS session as it looks like something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input dataset should be `work.compno_date_list`, not `work.date_list`.

```
proc sql noprint;
select distinct sdate into : sdatem  separated by ' '
from work.compno_date_list;
quit;

%put &sdatem;
```

Comment: date_list is an intermediate table that I created with just the distinct date values. But does it matter? even compno_date_list will give me the same distinct dates.